# When copying tables from one database and inserting into another with ADF, does the data duplicate when pipeline is run multiple times?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm wondering if -when doing copy activity- picking the "insert" option on the sink and running that pipeline multiple times, does that end up duplicating the data, or will it only insert new rows from the source tables into the sink tables after initial run?

Answer (score 0):

In case of insert, ADF only appends the data as is. So if the pipeline is run multiple times, it would duplicate the data at sink.
To avoid it, you can either use upsert option ( disadvantage is deleted record at source might not be deleted from sink) or use pre copy script at sink to truncate table at sink before running copy activity